# How to JSON.parse the chunk from http.get on 'data'?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to fetch something without the need of third-party package ( like node-fetch ) with http.get, when I try to fetch from jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts and then parse the chunk I receive `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input` however if I try the same with like /posts/1 the result comes back as expected ( valid json ), what's the issue?

my code:

```js
http.get(
  {
    host: 'jsonplaceholder.typicode.com',
    path: '/posts',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  },
  res => {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', chunk => {
      console.log(JSON.parse(chunk));
    });
  }
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't (as far as I know) parse fragments of JSON because they would be malformed(hence your exception). For instance...the following is not valid JSON:

```
{ 
  "name": "My npm package
```

because it's malformed (as your `SyntaxError` says).

Therefore, you would need to wait until the very end (`res.on('end', () => {})` and parse the data in there...

Try something like this:

```js
const data = [];
http.get(
  {
    host: 'jsonplaceholder.typicode.com',
    path: '/posts',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  },
  res => {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', chunk => {
      data.push(chunk);
    });
    res.on('end', () => {
        console.log(JSON.parse(data.join(''));
    });
  }
);
```